# How can I change an image when the user scrolls down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I can easily animate on scroll down png and jpg format images easily, but when I scroll down gif images, It repeatedly animated when I scroll down more.[image: Here i provide gif image]

this is the script i use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () { 
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10) { 
                    $('.navbar-brand-img img').attr('src','asserts/images/innvert.gif');
                }
                if ($(this).scrollTop() < 49) { 
                    $('.navbar-brand-img img').attr('src','asserts/images/expand.gif');
                }
            })
        });
</script>
```

Anyone can help

I want to animate logo of gif images i provide the model website that animation used

[Thrashio](https://www.thrasio.com/)

Comment: FYI they don't use 2 gifs.

Comment: Setting the `src=` of an image will always restart the image if it's animated, even if it's the same src= - and you re-set the src= (to the same value) *every* scroll   So you need to store whether or not you've already set the image. A simple flag or `.data` on the img would suffice.

Comment: You probably want to change to use `if/else` or change `if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10)` to `if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10 && $(this).scrollTop() < 49)` or some other range.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask] for tips.

Comment: Sorry, My straight question is, what is the script used in this website to animate the logo:  I tried to find it, but I cant the website link is: 
https://www.thrasio.com/

Comment: It starts as an `svg`, then there's a `data-image='data:image/gif...` so it looks like it changes the logo to an animated gif at a specific time, *once* (not on every scroll event) likely with a delay/timeout to convert it to the static image to coincide with when the gif finishes animating (I'm not "up" on whether you can have an gif that only animates once - I would probably repeat the last frame multiple times to match the timing as gif timings aren't exact across browsers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `src=` of an image will always restart the image if it's animated, even if it's the same `src=`.  Your issue is that you re-set the `src=` (to the same value) on *every* scroll so it's constantly restarting.

You can store whether or not you've already set the image - a simple flag (or .data on the img) would suffice.

```
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {

    // set to true/false here based on your initial image
    var invert = false;

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 10) {
      if (!invert) {
          $('.navbar-brand-img img').attr('src', 'asserts/images/innvert.gif');
          invert = true;
      }
    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < 49) {
      if (invert) {
          $('.navbar-brand-img img').attr('src', 'asserts/images/expand.gif');
          invert = false;
      }
    }
  })
});
```

Note your `>10` doesn't match with `<49` so may cause problems.